# CSS: trying to align a <p> on the right

Tags: css

i have this [page](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/miembros/show/id/2):

```
login: maria@mail.com
password: m
```

I want to have the string "Editar mi perfil" aligned on the right, so i have added:

```
text-align: right
```

but it doesn't work,

I have tried also:

```
float:right
```

It works but goes a bit upper than I want.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: I can't see "Editar mi perfil" on your page.

Comment: @Gert G: You must log in with the provided data.

Comment: @user248959: Over 80 questions, and only about 40 answers accepted? You should browse your old questions and reward the other 40 authors who helped you...

Comment: @Boldewyn - Oh, sorry. My brain hasn't woke up yet. :D

Comment: But really, you should make a publicly accessible test case that is guaranteed to last as long as StackOverflow exist, so that it may be used for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `display:inline`. Remove it (and perhaps the top margin, if you don't want it), and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

use `<div>` instead of `<p>`

```
<div style="float: left;">
  <h2 id="nombre_apellidos">Maria Galindo Alvarado</h2>
</div>

<div style="float:right;padding-top:0px;" id="editar_o_mensaje">
  <a id="enlace_editar_perfil" href="/rs2/web/miembros/edit/id/2">Editar mi perfil</a>      
</div>
```

Change proper `padding-top:0px;` to align

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float: right; padding-top: 5px;` in `enlace_editar_perfil` seems to fix it in Firefox. The `padding-top` will push it down to the position you want it.